# Highlight L.divIcon on mouseover or programmatically in Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to highlight `L.divIcon` svg markers on mouseover and/or from an "outside action" like pressing a button.

here is a simplified testcase https://jsfiddle.net/sxvLykkt/5/

Markers are generated dynamically (geoJson originally) and added to a `L.FeatureGroup()`.
On `mouseover` I set a bigger version of the icon (`divIconActive`) on a temporary layer, that I remove on mouseout. Unfortunately this doesn't work as indented (it's flickering on mouseover, the event is firing mouseover and mouseout I believe). How can I solve this.

And how can I access the markers when clicking one of the buttons? Somehow over their index I believe?! I can't wrap my head around.

Here is a portion of the code how the markers are created:

```
// init map and tileLayer -> jsfiddle
var coords = [[53, 13],[49, 10],[46, 12],[51, 16]];

$.each(coords, function(i,e){
  // create the button
  $('#controls').append('<button>'+i+'</button>')

  var marker = L.marker(e, {
    icon: divIcon,
    id: i
  });

  locationLayer.addLayer(marker);

  marker.on('mouseover', function(e){
    markerTemp = L.marker(e.latlng, {
        icon: divIconActive
    }).addTo(map);

  });

  marker.on('mouseout', function(e){
    markerTemp.remove();
  });

});

locationLayer.addTo(map);

$('button').on('click', function(e){
    alert('Highlight the right marker!')
});
```

Comment: Here is a working solution: gis.stackexchange.com/a/267444/112041

Answer (score 2):

First, to fix out marker problem, replace this code

> ```
> marker.on('mouseover', function(e){
>     markerTemp = L.marker(e.latlng, {
>         icon: divIconActive
>     }).addTo(map);
>
>   });
>
>   marker.on('mouseout', function(e){
>     markerTemp.remove();
> });
> ```

for this other

```
marker.on('mouseover', function(e){

    // place the hover State on a temp Layer
    markerTemp = L.marker(e.latlng, {
        icon: divIconActive
    }).addTo(map);

    markerTemp.on('mouseout', function(e){
      markerTemp.remove();
    });

});
```

Thus, the marker will be deleted when the mouse out the Big marker.

Then, one way to personalize the buttons click is:

Add one ID to the buttons when you create them:

```
$('#controls').append('<button id="button'+i+'">'+i+'</button>');
```

And later, after creating marker add the code for its button:

```
var marker = L.marker(e, {
    icon: divIcon,
    id: i
  });

  locationLayer.addLayer(marker);

  //the button for this marker
  $('#button'+i).on('click', function(e){
    alert(i);
    //Here you enter what you want to do
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. It's still flickering on hover. But here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/sxvLykkt/12/